# SerialPort/Angular send instructions to serialPort after reading its message

Tags: angular, electron, serial-port

I used 'ngx-serial' for my angular project and I want to send some data to the serialPort after reading the results it sends. I get those errors: [image]

Here is my code:

```
 dataHandler(data: string) {
    console.log("From serial port -> " + data);
    this.myResult = data.replace(/\r/g, '');;
    console.log('myResult: ', this.myResult);
    this.readMyStream(this.myResult);
  }
readMyStream(data: string) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const words = data.split(' ');
      if (words[0] === '**' && words[3] === '****') {
        this.serial.sendData(`*** ** ****\n`);
        console.log('hhihih'); // Alternatively, display message in template
      }
    }, 9000)
  }
```

Any suggestions?